# shell script filter question

Tags: shell, scripting

I am trying to store the resulting list from "ls -la" into a variable then filter out some files name, after that print out only the filtered file names (along with the date and stuff like how ls -la does it" again, but when I do that everything is in one line, is there a way to make sure every file name are on different lines?

thanks in advance

Comment: Show us what you have so far, and tell us which shell so we know what we have to work with.

Comment: Mind your quoting. Just about all uses of any variable should be inside double quotes to protect internal whitespace (like your line breaks) in the variable's value.

Comment: thankyou after reading the answer I got it to work now thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) instead of storing it in a variable.

```
ls -la | filter
```

Where `filter` is whatever you're using to filter.

That's about as good an answer as I can give unless you can provide some more details on exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to filter file names, eg , don't list all txt files

```
shopt -s extglob
ls !(*.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -al | grep -v "file-pattern-you-want-to-filter-out"
```